# Is there a kind of caching? - SVG (D3) Graph remembers its old position

Tags: d3.js

I'm backend developer for several years but a newbie in frontend issues.
I used "graphviz" (using d3.js) to draw an SVG graph from DOT notation. 
Everything is working fine but one thing I don't get in my mind:

If I "open" another (or the same one) graph its starting position is the 
same as this from the previous drawn graph even if I completely remove 
the whole node content from the dom as follows:

```
  var svg = d3.selectAll("svg");
  var otherBelow = svg.selectAll("*");
  otherBelow.remove();
  // svg.remove();
```

Doing this and checking the page source the nodes below SVG are realy dropped 
but drawing the new graph it has exactly the position of the previously 
moved graph in "transform" attribute. Doing a work around by resetting the 
position bevore solves this problem but then the problem remains for the 
"moving on mousedown" capability. Then the graph immediately "jumps" to the old 
ones position. But therefor I can't even get an information about somewhere 
in the page source. Really the generated page code is 100% the same (with 
diff tool) but has a different behaviour. Don't understand how this is possible.

So now my question: Is there a kind of caching? Or is there perhaps the 
browser cache used somehow internally? How to fix this?

P.s. if I remove the SVG node itself I get a completely courious behaviour. 
Then the newly drawn graph is not movable at all.

Comment: Add more code plz

Answer (score 0):

This (ugly) workaround does it for me.

```js
// Snipped to render a new graph and reset its position
// #graph -> id of d3-graphviz div-container

document.getElementById('graph').innerHTML = ''
setTimeout(() => {
  d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
    .dot(yourDotData)
    .render()
}, 50)
```

**Explanation/Assumption why this works:**

- It seems that the deletion of the old graph with `.innerHTML = ''`and the creation of the new one **should not happen in the same rendering phase/at the same time**, therefore the timeout function.
- The second part of the workaround is to **use a new graphivz-instance** to render the new graph, therefore the
  `d3.select(...)` within the timeout function.

Answer (score 0):

The graphviz renderer is still present on the element it was created on and has all its data still intact.

Removing the svg and then reuse the renderer is not a valid use case. Nico's answer is probably correct, but there are better ways to do it, but in order to tell you how you should do it instead I would need so see all of your code so I can understand what you *really* want to do.